# When customer Cancels Recurring Payment in Magento, will it cancel PayPal?

Tags: paypal, customer-account, recurring

I have a few Recurring Profiles in my Magento store, and have it attached to PayPal in sandbox mode. It appears that when I as a customer go to my (Magento) store account, go to Recurring Profiles, and Cancel it, PayPal continues to charge me. This would be horrible customer experience. Is it supposed to also cancel PayPal, or is this how it is intended to work?

If intended, how should the merchant assure the customer can intuitively cancel their subscription? Do I need to manually check every day for cancelled subscriptions, and send them an e-mail on how to also cancel in PayPal? :(

I'm on Magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: The profile cancellation code is in cancel() of app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Recurring/Profile.php. It seems that it is a local DB operation with no API calls to PayPal.

Comment: ^ Correction: It looks like updateRecurringProfileStatus() in app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Pro.php is actually doing an update over the API.